# При получении верного (несуществующего) пути/имени для файла, не вызывается метод createFile2(), а цикл запускается заново (отмечено стрелками)

Tags: java

```
public void createFile1() {
    NavigationMethods methodsOfNavigation = new NavigationMethods();
    File newFile = new File(userDataStr);
    if (!newFile.exists()) {
        createFile2();
    } else if (newFile.exists()) {
        while (newFile.exists()) {
              System.out.println("\n" + "File of this path and name already exists, try again! (Back to Action List (1))" + "\n");
   ===>       userDataStr = userData1.nextLine();
   ===>     if (!newFile.exists()) {
   ===>         createFile2();
            } else if (userDataStr.equals("1")) {
                methodsOfNavigation.listOfActions();
                methodsOfNavigation.choiceOfAction();
                methodsOfNavigation.actionsItself();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: newFile не обновляется, его присвоение вне цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объект `newFile` создаете один раз до старта цикла. Последующие изменения переменной `userDataStr` никак не влияют на объект `newFile`.

Кроме того, вы запутались в вызовах `newFile.exists()`. Вы никогда не выйдите из цикла с условием `while (newFile.exists())` если вы выполняете такой код

```
if (!newFile.exists()) {
    createFile2();
```

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно это

```
public void createFile1() {
    File newFile = new File(userDataStr);
    // Запрашиваем имя, пока не будет введен несуществующий файл
    while (newFile.exists()) {
      System.out.println("\n" + "File of this path and name already exists, try again! (Back to Action List (1))" + "\n");
      userDataStr = userData1.nextLine();
      newFile = new File(userDataStr);
    }
    // Вышли из цикла, значит файла нет. Создаем
    createFile2();
    // Запрашиваем действие
    userDataStr = userData1.nextLine();
    if (userDataStr.equals("1")) {
        NavigationMethods methodsOfNavigation = new NavigationMethods();
        methodsOfNavigation.listOfActions();
        methodsOfNavigation.choiceOfAction();
        methodsOfNavigation.actionsItself();
    }
}
```